# ColdFusion not displaying large query results in web page

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, odbc, hive, coldfusion-10

I have a Hive DSN set up using MapR ODBC Driver, and I can query Hive tables using this DSN from SQLServer (through Linked Server to Hive). No issues here.

For my web app, I use Apache ColdFusion to connect to this SQLServer, and I use the Hive linked server and query data. Web app works fine and I am able to display the query results in the webpage. Again, no issues here.

Question -
When I try to query and get large dataset as result, somehow the results are not displayed in the webpage.

For instance:
Results for this query can be successfully displayed in the webpage:

```
select * from Hive_Table LIMIT 10
```

same query, with higher `LIMIT` (say 20) does not return the result set (webpage does not show the results):

```
select * from Hive_Table LIMIT 20
```

I am able to get the results of BOTH queries above when I run directly from SQLServer (not from web app). So I guess this is not an issue with the Hive ODBC driver, but something to do with ColdFusion.

Is there any setting that is preventing this functionality? I changed the server timeout setting in admin page of CF (unchecked, so no timeout) - this didnt help.

Thanks.

**** ADDING MORE INFO****

This webpage (in CF) calls makes an AJAX call to a function in a CFC. The function returns the query, and the callback function in my webpage creates the table/column/row data by looping through the result (`response.DATA[i][j]` is looped over to get the result data, and an HTML table is created). The HTML table is then displayed in the webpage in a div.
The code works perfectly for `LIMIT 10`, but not for `LIMIT 20` :)

I use CF 10, jQuery, MapR Hive ODBC 64bit driver, SQLServer 2008.

Comment: Does this work? `<cfquery name="test" datasource="..." maxrows="20">select * from Hive_Table</cfquery>`

Comment: Based on your new edit, are you able to see the response back from AJAX call (for 20 rows) in your 'Firebug' kind of debugger?

Comment: 20 is very small resultset to make any difference. Is it possible that there is some data (which I believe you could be returning through json) which is throwing off your json? Use a browser debugging tool like firbug, see network, and notice what result is being returned, may be CFC have some problem. It can be anything which is difficult to tell but will be easier for you to figure out looking out your ajax call results.

Comment: It sounds to me like something in rows 11-20 has some content that JS doesn't like. What happens if you hit the URL directly, rather than via an AJAX request from JS? You need to *start* addressing this issue by factoring out some of the moving parts. You also need to include what troubleshooting steps you've already undertaken, which - from your description so far - sounds like "none".

Comment: @GauravS - there's no response back from AJAX call for limit=20. I use Chrome and the "inspect element" to see these details. Do not see any response there.

Comment: You should use the Network tab in Chrome, not the "Inspect element" There is nothing to inspect.

Comment: Ok.. So I used Firebug, and looking here, Net>All>JSON I see that the result is already there, but is not being displayed in the webpage. So is this an AJAX issue?

Comment: Apparently. And it is your task to find out why it is not working.

Comment: Do you see a response for limit - 10 rows? Just to ensure if you are looking at the right place.

Comment: @GauravS - I see response for 10 and 20 in the firebug plugin. There seems to be some inconsistency in displaying the 10 row result in the html page. Sometimes it does, other times it doesnt. I think it could be a code issue. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Glad I could help. Do let us know what the exact issue is/was and how did you resolve.

Answer (score 0):

20 cannot by any standards be considered a "large dataset" and no, Coldfusion doesn't have any specific limits on the number of records to show. Try to dump the query on the page. What do you see?

Comment: thanks for looking into this. I've added more info into the question. Yes, Limit 20 is not large :) But approximately at this limit, my code breaks (i get no result). Limit 10, and lower is fine.

Comment: Forget about drivers. Check the AJAX response in Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools and find out what breaks it.